# Prevent /new action being replaced in URL after failed validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

After a failed validation I would like the user's brower to display the /new action in the URL not the /create action (which replaces /new after every failed validation). Any way to do this with rails?

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end


def create
   @user = User.new(params[:user])

   if @user.save
     redirect_to success_path
   else
     render 'new'
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with a redirect using the session instead:

```
def new
  if session[:new_user_params].present?
    @user = User.new(session[:new_user_params])
    @user.valid?
  else
    @user = User.new
  end
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  if @user.save
    session.delete(:new_user_params)
    redirect_to success_path
  else
    session[:new_user_params] = params[:user]
    redirect_to action: :new
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think the validation errors are saved with this approach, or?

Comment: True. I've updated my answer to also call `valid?` in the right case. May I ask why you want to do this? This really isn't a RESTful way and not the way Rails is intended on being used.

Comment: @Vapid Thank you. Indeed you are right, however, this is just one of many steps in a multi-step form. Also, exposing the /create action to the user is not exactly professional as it exposes too much of the 'plumbing' of the app. Any alternative (RESTful) approach would be appreciated.

Comment: I see. Then using the session and the new method for that is probably the best thing. For two more multi step solutions you can check out these [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=✓&search=wizard).